# Xcode Interface Builder View Editing within same controller

Tags: iphone, xcode, view, interface-builder, storyboard

Is there a easy way to access views within Xcode?

I am making a game where I have several views in the phone size(480x320), but different elements within each.

When I trying to click on a button and drag it in view to, I can't, because all I clicking is view 1(view 1 is on top of view 2)

I know you can select it from the left panel on elements, but when you want resize and drag it is actually more easier to do it through interface builder rather than changing it attributes,  it would be good to be able individually access the sub-view in a single window, or some smart functions does the similar thing.

Any smart idea if Xcode supports such thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have outlets to each view, then make them strong, don't put the views in the main view, but tile them outside it (if you don't have outlets now, you'll have to create them).

You can easily edit then (although Xcode will rearrange them often). In your code, when the view loads, add these views as subviews in the primary view. You also need to nil them in viewDidUnload (which is a bit of a pain), or if you just added the outlets so as to place them in the view.subview, you can nil the property after you add them to your subview.